# How to change NgbCollapse default value of false?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

The default value for ngbCollapse is false, as described at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse.  The example given there uses the following code: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/collapse/demos/basic/plnkr.html

```
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
      You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How does one over-ride the default so that the toolbar is collapsed by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Noticed the same thing. Initialize the variable in a constructor and it works fine.

```
export class AppComponent {
  isCollapsed:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isCollapsed = true;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is useful to have some bite-size examples like this of how the different pieces fit together.

Comment: I would suggest instead utilizing the built-in properties provided with the ngBootstrap Collapse Module

Answer (score 1):

Modifying this within the Typescript seems to drive away from the intent of using the module's provided properties. Instead, by utilize `[ngbCollapse]` you do not need add to Typescript and have more control with the advantage of ngDirectives.

`<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="!isCollapsed">`

Additionally, when used within dynamically generated content (`*ngFor...[ngbCollapse]=`) you can take advantage of ng-if-else conditional states

`*ngIf="getIsEditing(buffer); then tableEdit; else tableView;"`